# Physics of the freezer fix

Tags: power-supply, physics

**Context:**

I often open up the freezer to my roommate's old laptop power supply.

It's the only way he knows to make it work, otherwise the power supply does not power up the laptop (and the status led does not light up). *According to him, putting it in the freezer for about 30 minutes makes it reliably work.*

I can attest to the unreliability of the power supply, and also to its regular working status: I've seen it work just this morning. This has been going on for multiple months, and the power supply goes needs to go in the freezer a few times every week.

**Questions:**

- Is there any way in which putting the power supply in the freezer can really help?
- If so, what are the physical phenomena involved?

Comment: Could be a bad solder joint or connection that fixes itself due to thermal contraction of something in the cold temperature, then finally loses contact after being at operating temperature for a while.  No way to know for sure without actually debugging the supply.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple, thermal expansion. Most likely there is a cracked solder joint or something along those line inside that is causing an open. Chilling the power supply makes the things inside contract closing the crack. The closed crack will make contact until the power supply gets hot again. Predicting exactly what failed to give the symptoms that you described is not possible without dissembling the supply and diagnosing it.